# Cake PHP issue of folder creation in views

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I am new to cake php. I read the blog tutorial of cakephp. According to blog tutorial for every  new controller a new folder in views should be created. I want to avoid folders creation  in view except one folder in views .and that folder should be "Layout folder"...how this goal should be achieved, please try to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $this->render('/Layout'.DS.newthread);
```

Here `Layout` is folder name and **newthread** is file name(eg: newthread.ctp)

You have to add this line in every function

```
public function some(){
    $this->render('/Layout'.DS.newthread);
}
```

[Read this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#interacting-with-views) cakebook for more information